# How many animated Smurfs movies have been made?

Tags: movie, smurfs

I mostly curious, but how many animated *Smurfs* movies were made?
I figured that there had to be more than 2 at least.

Comment: The answer is "too many" if they made any at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs#Other_media), there have been 6 feature films starring the Smurfs.

- [The Adventures of the Smurfs (1965)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Aventures_des_Schtroumpfs) (hand-drawn animation)
- [The Smurfs and the Magic Flute (1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs_and_the_Magic_Flute) (hand-drawn animation)
- [Smurfs (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs_(film)) (which features a blend of computer animation and live-action)
- [The Smurfs: A Christmas Carol (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs:_A_Christmas_Carol) (which features a blend of computer animation and hand-drawn animation)
- [Smurfs 2 (2013)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs_2) (which features a blend of computer animation and live-action)
- [Smurfs: the Lost Village (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurfs:_The_Lost_Village) (wholly computer animated)

---

Several other full length or extra-length features were 'made-for-TV' by combining existing episodes and adding filler.

- [The Baby Smurf (1984)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0258438/)
- [Here are the Smurfs (1984)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0258649/)
- [The Smurfs Christmas Special (1982)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1177949/?ref_=kw_li_tt)
- ['Tis the Season to Be Smurfy (1987)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198267/?ref_=kw_li_tt)

Comment: Thanks, but I’m asking about ANIMATED smurf movies, so the 2011 & the 2013 movies wouldn’t qualify, sorry

Comment: They're all animated. Some also feature live action elements

Comment: Oh , I didn’t consider that @Valorum